# Is the union of a set of ordinals a nonlimit ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set of nonlimit ordinals less than a given $\kappa$, and let the union $A$ be also less than $\kappa$. Does this union have to be a nonlimit ordinal if

1. $\kappa=\omega$;
2. $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal.

In the first case, the answer is yes? $A$ must be a subset of omega such that $\bigcup A < \omega$. So $A$ must be finite? And then the union will be a limit ordinal?

In the second case, I tried to consider $\aleph_1$. But here it is unclear how to describe its subsets $A$ for which $\bigcup A < \aleph_1$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1,  it is trivially true since the first limit ordinal is $\omega$ and you are given that the union is less than $\omega$

For 2, it's easily shown to be false.  Just take $A$ to be all the natural numbers.  Then their union is a limit ordinal $\omega$

Comment: And if A were an arbitrary set of limit ordinals less than ℵ1, whose union is also less than ℵ1, would this union have to be a limit ordinal?

Comment: There's only 1 limit ordinal less than $\aleph_1$,  it is by definition the next larger one to $\aleph_0$

Comment: But what about $ω+ω$ and others like it?